# Web Platform Installer (WPI) alternative / Replacement

Tags: asp.net, iis, webdeploy, web-platform-installer

I'm trying to setup a Web Deploy publish method within Visual Studio for an ASP.NET Web Application [Web Forms project]. In all the learn.microsoft articles it recommends Web Platform Installer (WPI). However WPI has been sunset and it's not supported/Running.

I've attempted to install the Web Deploy portion individually, however VS is unable to connect with: "Could not connect to the remote computer. On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service" is started."

The documentation specifically states that installing Web Deploy directly "will not configure Web Management Service"

That said, what's the recommended way of configuring a Web Server (Windows Server 2022), to be the target of a Web Deploy Publish?

Comment: You can also try to fix this error, deleting all the web deploy folders in program files(x86)\IIS and in Program Files\IIS and then reinstalled [web deploy](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy).

Comment: I've tried uninstalling, removing the files and re-installing, no luck. It installs the "Web Deployment Agent Service", but not the "Web Management Service", which is what Visual Studios is erroring out on when trying to do a "Web Publish" to that site.

Comment: FYI the Web Deploy installer does work for "Web Deploy Package" publish methods, which I will use in the mean time, but I'd prefer not to have to run the packages, and just keep everything within Visual Studio.

Comment: If you want to deploy asp.net to IIS by visual studio you can refer to this link: [Deploy ASP.NET To IIS By Visual Studio](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis-by-visual-studio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to locate a method of installing "Web Management Service" through the Management Tools within Add Features, or by using PowerShell. I followed the article here: [Install IIS Web Management Service for Remote IIS Administration and Management](https://www.saotn.org/install-and-setup-iis-manager-for-remote-administration-in-windows-server-iis/#install-iis-web-management-service-for-remote-iis-administration-and-management), which goes step by step to install, start, and configure the Firewall rules. I'll describe them here incase that link stops working in the future.

1. Install Management Service: This can be done with PowerShell running as Admin:
   `Install-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Service`
   Or by opening "Add Remote Features" wizard > Server Roles > Web Server (IIS) > Management Tools > And selecting "Management Service"
2. Enable Remote Management: This can be done using PowerShell as well: `Set-ItemProperty HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server -Name EnableRemoteManagement -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force` & `Set-ItemProperty HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server -Name RequiresWindowsCredentials -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force`.. However this step did not work for me, and instead I used IIS > Select the Server Node from the Connection Tree view (left side) > Double Click "Management Services" > Check "Enable Remote Connections" and Selecting Apply and Start. *Note If options are grayed out you only need to press stop from the action pane to stop the service*
3. Add IIS Remote Management Rule in Windows Firewall: PowerShell- By Service:  `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IIS Remote Management" dir=in action=allow service=WMSVC` or By Port: `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IIS Remote Management" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8172` or by using the Windows Firewall GUI.

There are also some additional resources I found while drafting this response here: [Configuring remote Administration and feature delegation in IIS 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/remote-administration/configuring-remote-administration-and-feature-delegation-in-iis-7) which goes into more details upon configuring the Management Service and IIS after the fact to get it connect. I had several validation errors when initially setting up the Web Deploy package for my Visual Studio project, but I was able to troubleshoot those issues and get the publish to run successfully to the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

If you require the `Web Platform Installer` to access the [Downloads for IIS](https://www.iis.net/downloads) like [Web Deploy 3.6](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy), you can conveniently obtain them from the following link: https://iis-umbraco.azurewebsites.net/downloads.

Please note that there are two categories available for other downloads:

- [Community Contributed Downloads](https://www.iis.net/downloads/community)
- [Microsoft Supported Downloads](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft)

Answer (score -2):

Well, for one, you don't mention what kind of web site this is?

Is it a asp.net web site? Or is this a asp.net web site application?

I often for example do a "local" publish. That results in a folder on my local computer that can be "transferred" to the server running IIS.

So, in that case, I publish like this:

[image]

At that point, I have a folder called "Web".

I then zip the file, and then can remote into the web server, and I copy this folder (I zip it, since copy of one file goes much faster). And the site is about 110 megs in size, but zipped, it's about 46 megs.

So, once I have the folder on the server, then I unzip (to a folder called stage).

I then stop IIS, copy the files to the site folder  (C:\inetpub\wwwroot), and then start IIS.

Now, I COULD publish as FTP, but I turned FTP off (for increased security).

And while I am remoted into the server (remote desktop), I can only do as such via a VPN, and the public facing port(s) don't have nor allow RDP.

Also when I'm on site, or on the same network, I will publish directly to a shared folder on the network (so, saves a bit of time, don't have to publish local, then zip).

So, I'm using vs2022, and the web site publish option works quite well, and gives the option to publish to a folder, publish via FTP, or of course that 3rd option of using web deploy options. However, I don't like (nor use that option), again for reasons of increased security.

And I could probably setup a batch file/script that somewhat help and automate this process a bit further, however I'm only updating the site say a few times a week, so it well under a five minute task anyway.

My web site is a asp.net website "application" (web forms, .net 4.8), using vs2022 for this.

So, when I publish, then of course all source code is stripped out, project is compiled, and the resulting folder is a web server ready web site. At that point, all I have to do is copy (over write) the existing site, and I do stop IIS for this copy). Note that I thus use what is called "x-copy" updates. There are 1 or 2 folders on the side that I don't have on my development computer, and that's the folders for Let's Encrypt and that enables the https security certificate part, which I don't use during development.

So, on my dev computer, I run the site/project as http, but in production, it of course runs as https.

I also of course use the "web.config" transform that works during the publish process that updates the connection strings from my local computer (.\SQLEXPRESS) to the actual server name + sql instance and passwords during the publish process).

And while I as noted am using a asp.net web site "application" as opposed to a asp.net web site: a web site ALSO has the publishing wizard and option - and it works for web sites, and it works even in vs2022.

So, you not noted if you have FTP ability, but that's a possible. And as noted, publish to a folder, and then finding a means to copy that resulting folder to the server is really all you require here.

Much of this "choice" and "road" will depend on what type of site you have, and do you have options like say remote desktop, or a VPN or FTP.

Comment: Albert, I was specifically asking for "Web Deploy" which is a specific type of Publish Method that you provide a Server, Site Name, username/password and a destination URL and it will publish from my local Visual Studio to the remote/target Server. What you're describing sounds more familiar to a "File System" publish, which is what we're trying to get away from. 

I suggest you take a look at the Web Deploy or Web Package deploy as those publish methods will add/remove/update files to the web application for you.

Comment: You just noted that WPI it is "sun set", right? My answer certainly takes into account that fact. Might not be great that I pointing this out, but my answer is in that context - in other words, you asking how to move away from WPI and what to use? I suggest that you use publish from vs, and adopt FTP or vpn, and work using that approach.  I mean, if you not open to any other answer and approach, then why did you bother asking then? Either you drop WPI or you don't. At that point, then you using web publish from vs then, right? If you have better ideas then do share what you plan to use here?

Comment: If a bunch of people pile in to this post and offer you help? Then great, but they don't seem to be, are they? I'll just avoid you and your questions in the future - that will make us both happy then, right?  Sorry my ideas and advice are of little help.

Comment: WPI is separate from Web Deploy.  WPI is the application / interface that used to allow simple installation of Web tools, Web Deploy is a stand alone installer that you could use WPI to install, and in doing is it would also install "Web Management Service". I even specifically asked for a Web Deploy solution at my final sentence. I understand that your answer is an alternative to Web Deploy, and another way to publish an application to a server, however I'm looking for something more automated.